# Javascript regex to check for a word followed by a character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a `sql` which looks like below

```
sql = "select avg     ( total_cost) from business ;"
```

OR

```
sql = "select avg(total_cost) from business ;"
```

Now I want to check if `avg` or `max` followed by (one or more whitespace) `(` is present in the `sql`

This is my regex

```
var patt = new RegExp(/(avg|max|min|count|sum\s*[(])/);
var check = patt.test(sql);
```

It works when `avg` is present in the query but if the query is like below

```
select (total_cost) from business ;
```

It still gives match for the condition.

The final result should be

```
sql = "select avg     ( total_cost) from business ;"    -->true
sql = "select max( total_cost) from business ;"         -->true
sql = "select avg_cost from business ;"                 -->false
sql = "select max total_cost from business ;"           -->false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your regex must be `/(avg|max|min|count|sum)\s*\(/`, or even probably `/\b(?:avg|max|min|count|sum)\s*\(/`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DhMF5k/1). BTW, `select (total_cost) from business ;` does not match your regex.

Comment: `avg|max|sum\s*[(])` means "match a) 'avg' or b) 'max', or c) `sum` followed by one or more whitespace characters followed by '('", not "match 'avg', 'max' or `sum`, that match followed by one or more whitespace characters followed by '('. It's analogous to writing `1+2*3` when you mean `(1+2)*3`. `[(])` is OK but it is conventionally written `\(`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh I was close :D You may post this as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the explanation buddy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
/\b(?:avg|max|min|count|sum)\s*\(/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DhMF5k/2) and the regex graph:

[image]

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:avg|max|min|count|sum)` - a non-capturing group matching any of the words inside
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char.